# Error build/preview Vite

Tags: reactjs, vite, build, dependencias, bug

Quise hacer un build de aplicación Vite + React, el build sale bien pero cuando hago npm run preview, no funciona.

vite.config.js

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite"
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react"
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';

export default defineConfig(async () => {
  const mdx = await import("@mdx-js/rollup")
  return {
    optimizeDeps: {
      include: ["react/jsx-runtime"],
    },
    plugins: [react(), mdx.default({ remarkPlugins: [] }), commonjs(), external({
      includeDependencies: true
    }),],

  }
})
```

**ERROR:** Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "vite/modulepreload-polyfill". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

**Prueba solución**
Siguiendo: https://vitejs.dev/config/build-options#build-polyfillmodulepreload

```
import external from "rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external";
import { defineConfig } from "vite"
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react"
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';

export default defineConfig(async () => {
  const mdx = await import("@mdx-js/rollup")
  return {
    optimizeDeps: {
      include: ["react/jsx-runtime"],
    },
    plugins: [react(), mdx.default({ remarkPlugins: [] }), commonjs(), external({
      includeDependencies: true
    }),],
    build: {
      polyfillModulePreload: false
    }
  }
})
```

**Nuevo ERROR:** Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "react/jsx-runtime". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".